# I got Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to remove it and get Windows 7. How do I do that?

Tags: windows-7, format

Need to switch from Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows 7 on my laptop.

Help please. I need it ASAP for work. I got the ISO for Windows 7 but don't know how to get rid of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the windows media on your drive, reboot your pc and keep pressing F12 until the box appear and you can select your driver to boot the cd, if the cd is bootable.

Answer (score 1):

Burn the ISO to a disc. Then insert the disk into the DVD Drive of your laptop. During the setup, it will ask you where to install Windows.Then click "Drive Options" [image: Click on Advanced Drive settings] Then you will see a list of drives and partitions similar to this:[image] Now you will be able to either remove Ubuntu completely or just re-size the partition. Now you can install Windows 7 by itself or with Ubuntu alongside it.